# Implements sending OOB SMS without user concern, is it possible?

Tags: android, performance, google-play, voicemail

Our Android application is a Visual VoiceMail application which communicates with IMAP server to doownload voicemail mails and play it on user handset. As an autentication method application implements sending/receiving OOB SMS from this client. For sending SMS for this application we have following queries

1. Will our application be allowed to host on playstore as the application is supposed to send OOB SMS whitout letting the user know about it as it is a part of standard authorization method. In reply to this SMS  server will response back to this client with an SMS over specific port which will have the credentials for user and client will start working.
2. If above is not allowed then what are the norms with which we can implement the same behaviour. Please not we cannot ask the user every time to allow sending messages from application.
3. Will it be ok if we take consent from user at the time of installation that this application will send authorization/validation messages from backend.
4. Any other suggestion and norms which we need to take care.
5. The Visual VoiceMail application is limited to users of a particular operator.
6. This SMS will not charge any cost to the user, It will be free.

Is this possible and allowed for application to be published on Google Play. If not, please suggest a way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.